# I need to figure what % of our total monthly income I contribute.

Tags: percentages

If I make ${$}1100$ month and my husband makes ${$}2720$ month (total combined ${$}3820$ month), what percent do I make of our total monthly income and what percent does my husband make of our total monthly income?

Comment: Think about how you get a percentage. Usually it's something like x/total. In this case you know the total and you know x(the amount each of you make). Can you handle the rest now?

Comment: Yup thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Percentage of total income will be the ratio of your income to the total income, multiplied by $100$ (for scaling purposes).

Your income:
$$\frac{1100}{3820} \approx 0.2880= 28.80\%$$

Therefore, your husband's contribution is (approximately):
$100\% -28.80\% = 71.20\%$

Comment: You need to be extremely careful. These numbers are incorrect.

Comment: $\frac{1100}{3820}\neq0.3039$ and even more obviously $0.3039\neq30.39$.

Comment: That's better. Now just change the "$=$" to "$\approx$".

Comment: Whoops, typed it in wrong on the calculator, sorry folks. @barakmanos if you look carefully, there's a percent sign on the next line.

Comment: Escape with \ to typeset the percent symbol; `$28.80\%$` will give you want you want there (this is how you deal with things like curly braces as well; same principle).

Comment: @infinitylord: I'm still seeing $0.2880=28.80$ (with no percent sign next to it).

Comment: @barakmanos: Strange. On my screen, there is a percent sign on the following line. I'm not sure how to format it to get the percent sign to appear properly.

Comment: Oh yeah, it is on the following line... Not very useful down there, isn't it?

Comment: acute observation.

Comment: It looks fine on my screen. None of these comments useful to OP or anyone else

Answer (score 1):

You: $$\frac{1100}{1100+2720}\cdot100\approx28.8\%$$

---

Him: $$\frac{2720}{1100+2720}\cdot100\approx71.2\%$$

Answer (score 0):

We may use the "standard" proportion formula for this $${x\over100} = {\text{part}\over\text{whole}}.$$ Considering your income only, then the "part" is $\$1100$, and the whole is $\$3820$. So, $${x\over100} = {1100\over3820} \implies x = 100\times{1100\over3820} \approx 28.80\%. $$ So you make about $28.80\%$ of the income. Then your husband's contribution is simply $100\% - 28.80\% = 71.2\%$.

Answer (score 0):

$\text{Percentage} = \frac{\text{Person Contribution}}{\text{Total}} \times 100$

Your -

$= \frac{1100}{1100 + 2720} \times 100$

Your husband -

$= \frac{2720}{1100 + 2720} \times 100$